# Swift, has got me on this one: interfaceOrientation was deprecated in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

It's not a do or die, but have not had any luck with hacking this. Thanks.

```
  if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput){

    session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)

    self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

      // ERROR HERE
      let orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation =  AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: self.interfaceOrientation.rawValue)!

      (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.videoOrientation = orientation

    })
  }
```

[image]

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, it was depecrated. You can use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation` instead.

```
let orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation?

switch UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation{
case .LandscapeLeft:
    orientation = .LandscapeLeft
case .LandscapeRight:
    orientation = .LandscapeRight
case .Portrait:
    orientation = .Portrait
case .PortraitUpsideDown:
    orientation = .PortraitUpsideDown
case .Unknown:
    orientation = nil
}

if let orientation = orientation{
    (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.videoOrientation = orientation
}
```

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation` throws "Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIApplication'" during the build in XCode 8.0 

Comment: Look for preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation property in the view controller. Tested on Xcode 8.0